# Spatie Multi Tenancy. Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-livewire

I have a Multi Tenancy web application.  I have a new client creation form that is used to populate a new client in the landlord.tenants database and then create the required database with seeded tables.  To achieve this I run the following commands from the Livewire Class(controller).

```
//Create DataBase
Artisan::call('db:create-tenant '.$this->database);
//Create tables and seed.
Artisan::call('tenants:artisan "migrate --seed" --tenant='.$new_tenant->id);
return redirect()->route('new_client.menu');
```

As you can see I pass the new database name to the db:create-tenant command and the new tenants id to the tenants:artisan "migrate --seed" --tenant= command as instructed in the spatie docs.

The commands run successfully creating the db and the seeded tables but the process always ends with error **Call to a member function prepare() on null**.

The error happens in
**C:\Users\------\code\---------\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:513**

I have removed the return redirect as part of my debugging and also removed the return on the livewire render function to rule that out.  All end in the same error.

Also, if I run the artisan commands from the terminal they work fine.

Anyone had this issue before or have an idea why it is happening?

Thanks in advance

Paul.

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers on [this github issue](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy/issues/285)?

Comment: I tried it and yes the error did go away, but the wrong table was being seeded.  Remove the command and the correct table is seeded but with the error.